# Accessing JSON properties when not using struct

Tags: go

I have some JSON and I need to be able to access the properties. As the JSON properties can vary I can't create a `struct` to unmarshal into.

**Example**

The JSON could be this:

```
{"name" : "John Doe", "email" : "john@doe.com"}
```

or this:

```
{"town" : "Somewhere", "email" : "john@doe.com"}
```

or anything else.

How can I access each of the properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unmarshal it into an `interface{}`. If you do that, `json.Unmarshal` will unmarshal a JSON object into a Go map.

For example:

```
var untypedResult interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(..., &untypedResult)

result := untypedResult.(map[string]interface{})

// ... now you can iterate over the keys and values of result ...
```

See <http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go#TOC_5.> for a complete example.

Comment: Silly question but how do I access just one specific property. I've tried `result.name` but this produce an error

Comment: @tommyd456: `result["name"]`.

Comment: Also you don't need to have separate cast, you can just do `var result map[string]interface{}` and use it in `Unmarshal`. Here is an example: http://play.golang.org/p/QeL8lIinQf

Answer (score 0):

If you just happen to have fields that may not be specified, you can unmarshal your input into a struct with pointer. If the field isn't present, the pointer will be `nil`.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    A *string
    B *string
    C *int
}

func main() {
    var input string = `{"A": "a","C": 3}`
    var foo Foo
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &foo)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", foo)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MkNCmM1IVp)

If you really want something more flexible, you can also unmarshal your input into a `map[string]interface{}`.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var input string = `{"A": "a","C": 3}`
    var foo map[string]interface{} = make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &foo)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", foo)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/YeSzrcXfyt)

Answer (score 0):

When unmarshalling a JSON document, not all properties that are defined in the struct need to be present in the JSON document. In your example, you could define the following struct:

```
type MyJson struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Town string `json:"town"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}
```

When your use this struct to unmarshal a JSON document that has one or more of these properties missing, they will be initialized with the respective type's null value (an empty string for `string` properties).

---

**Alternatively**, you can use the generic `interface{}` type for unmarshalling and then use type assertions. This is documented in-depth in the [blog post "JSON and GO"](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go):

```
var jsonDocument interface{}

err := json.Unmarshal(jsonString, &jsonDocument)
map := jsonDocument.(map[string]interface{})
town := map["town"].(string);
```